# Зачем нужны блочная и поразрядная сортировки?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c, c++

Я читал про разные типы сортировок, пять из которых известны всем хорошо. Я их легко освоил.

1. Пузырьковая сортировка
2. Сортировка вставкой
3. Сортировка слиянием
4. Сортировка выборкой
5. Быстрая сортировка

Но есть две сортировки, которые я не смог понять (отличие от других, и когда они применимы). Это

1. Карманная сортировка (блочная, Bucket Sort)
2. Корневая сортировка (поразрядная, Radix Sort)

Не могли бы прояснить, где лучше их использовать, их преимущества и отличия, а также буду рад ссылкам (или прямому коду) на простейшие реализации данных алгоритмов на С или С++.

Comment: Я бы еще порекомендовал шейкерную, шелла и бинарными вставками посмотреть.

Answer (score 27):

В отличие от сортировок 1–5, которые требуют от типа данных лишь операции сравнения, задающей линейный порядок, карманная и поразрядная (radix) сортировки предполагают, что нам известно больше о сортируемых элементах, за счёт чего они работают за *O(n)* от размера входных данных, преодолевая теоретический барьер *O(n log(n))* для сортировок 1–5.

1. Карманная сортировка (*bucket sort*)

   Этот алгоритм предполагает, что входные данные — числа, распределённые равномерно на некотором отрезке (скажем, [0; 1]). Разобьём этот отрезок на n частей, и распределим по ним данные n чисел. Ожидается, что в каждую часть попадёт немного элементов, а, значит, к ним можно применить простую и быструю сортировку (например, вставками). Ответом будет объединение результатов сортировки частей. Алгоритм требует *O(n)* дополнительной памяти и, в случае равномерного распределения входных данных, работает за *O(n)*. [Обоснование асимптотики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9E.D1.86.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8).
2. Поразрядная сортировка (*radix sort*)

   Этот алгоритм предполагает, что сортируются целые числа от 0 до C, представленные в позиционной системе счисления c основанием k (например, 2^8 или 2^16). Пойдём циклом по разрядам чисел от младших к старшим. Заведём массив count размером k, т.ч. count[i] = число элементов, имеющих в текущем разряде i (это делается линейным проходом по элементам). Далее, рассчитаем суммы на префиксах массива count (т.е. pref[i] это сумма count[j] для всех j меньше i. Теперь пройдёмся по сортируемым числам, кладя их в новом массиве на место pref[текущий разряд числа] и увеличивая этот элемент pref. После такого прохода за *O(n + k)* числа окажутся стабильно отсортированными по текущему разряду, а значит, в силу стабильности, и по всем более младшим разрядам. В конце все числа будут стабильно отсортированы.
   Работает данная реализация за *O((n + k) * log_k(C))*, что, в принципе, является *O(n)* (k и C от n не зависят). Также этот алгоритм можно модифицировать для быстрой сортировки строк в лексикографическом порядке, если развернуть внешний цикл и избежать копирования строк в процессе работы алгоритма.
   [Некоторые реализации](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Radix_sort).

С практической точки зрения, когда сортируются числа, о которых не известно почти ничего, *quicksort*, обладая теоретически худшей асимптотикой, практически всегда обгоняет эти алгоритмы. В принципе, очень хорошо написанный *radixsort* может обогнать *heapsort/mergesort*, если от сортировки требуется стабильность. *Bucketsort* очень хорош, если входные данные подчиняются требуемому распределению, но это бывает не слишком часто.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Блочная сортировка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) Идея в том чтобы пользуясь какими-то известными заранее свойствами входных данных раскидать последовательность в n корзин. После этого все, что попало в отдельную корзину, сортируется либо рекурсивно таким же методом, либо другими методами. Если известно что данные раскидываются по корзином равномерно, получится что в корзину попадет мало элементов и в среднем алгоритм будет работать за O(n)
2. [radix sort](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) Применяется для сортировки последовательностей, сравниваемых лексикографически. Есть два варианта: либо сортировать с младшего положения к старшему стабильной сортировкой, либо отсортировать блочной сортировкой по первому символу, а затем корзины отсортировать рекурсивно по второму символу, и т.д.

Comment: Непонятна временная оценка для блочной сортировки. Если мы имеем на вход n элементов, мы можем раскидать их по к корзинам. Эту операцию мы выполним за O(n). Далее мы должны отсортировать каждую корзину. Если на этом шаге мы будем использовать, к примеру сортировку слиянием, то общее время будет O(n Log n). Если мы вызовем вызовем блочную сортировку рекурсивно, опять же, никак не выйдет O(n). В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Мы пользуемся тем что данные распределены примерно равномерно, а значит в каждую корзину попадет O(1) элементов. Без дополнительных предположений об исходной последовательности преодолеть O(n*log(n)) все равно не получится

Comment: Получается, что мы за один проход ставим элемент на свое место в выходной последовательности? Не понятно как такое сделать. Такое возможно только при наличии частично упорядоченных данных. Данная сортировка не тянет на самостоятельность. Или мне не уловить идею.

Comment: Нет, фишка в том что в каждую корзину в среднем константное число элементов, которые мы потом быстро отсортируем внутри каждой корзины. Например если нам нужно сортировать равномерно распределенные на интервале [0,1) числа, можно раскидывать их по корзинам [0,1/n), [1/n,2/n),.., [(n-1)/n,1). Тогда по теории вероятности в каждый интервал попадает в среднем одно число (если их было n).

Answer (score 3):

в книжке Каррано Ф.М., Причард Дж. Абстракция данных и решение задач на C++. Стены и зеркала
приводится пример реализации последних двух сортировок и даются некоторые комментарии

Answer (score 3):

на малочисленных объёмах данных рекоммендуется quicksort

на больших объёмах рекоммендуется [merge sort](http://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A1%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0_%25D1%2581%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BC&ei=OjJWU9iqO8vQ4QSgwIDwCQ&usg=AFQjCNE6UQ4YSUtWK6h7CUuhMR8hHGzmEw&sig2=L1u2K6e2vygrcpBN9flxGg&bvm=bv.65177938,d.bGE), c использованием многопоточности

если по какой-то причине лучше не использовать многопоточность, например, данные не достаточно большие, чтобы ощутим был выигрыш от распаралеливания, или, просто одноядерная система на атомной станции, то лучше использовать [heapsort](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), у которой асимптотика немного лучше

в стандартной библиотеке алгоритмов можно найти их реализации http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

остальные алгоритмы сортировок, пожалуй, не имеет практического смысла в применении

Comment: Рекомендую познакомится с timsort и introsort.

Comment: @Arnial, спасибо, timsort использует merge sort (слиянием) и используется для ускорения сортировки уже частично сортированных данных - довольно специальный случай, но выглядит полезно. Что касается второго гибридного алгоритма, introsort - он использует quick sort и переключается на heap sort - heap sort не очень хорошо параллелится (см. http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2016/01/multi-thread-heap-sort.html) - практического толку для больших данных нет, а для маленьких да. Хотя можно и по размеру выбирать quicksort/heapsort. Выбирать quicksort/heapsort/mergesort - уже новый гибридный алгоритм.