# Безопасное хранение соли

Tags: безопасность, криптография, хеширование

Что более безопасно и чем:

- хранить одну общую соль для всех паролей пользователей  в переменной среды
- или хранить свою для каждого пользователя соль в той же таблице, что и хэши?

Comment: Конкатенируй прямо к хэшу, чтобы он был внешне похож на хэш другого формата...

Comment: @Akina то есть, лучше в базе, но у каждого пользователя своя?

Comment: В причинах, по которым можно отдать голос за закрытие темы, есть "Невозможно дать объективный ответ. Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ." Самый Ваш случай.

Comment: @Akina вопрос "как сложнее будет злоумышленникам - украсть соль из переменных среды или работать с кучей известных солей" лучше?

Comment: Да пусть крадут! Алгоритм надо прятать, а не соль.

Comment: @Akina так большинство же вопросов инженерных и связанных с безопасностью не имеют одного универсально верного ответа и зависят от многих обстоятельств. Но это же не значит, что все такие важные тем надо запрещать обсуждать?) Лучше не полениться и описать разные варианты, их плюсы и минусы, границы применимости, best practices. И в [аналогичном вопросе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999247/5308802) дали несколько хороших ответов.

Comment: @AivanF. Ну так и задавать вопрос надо по конкретной ситуации, нормально её описывая. А "как оно там вообще" - это не на один том потянет... и всё равно, что ни напиши, к любому варианту легко прикладывается "хотя в случае, когда..." - и ещё плюс один многотомник. Со своими "хотя в случае"...

Comment: @Akina оно как бы так, но что человек без опыта ещё скажет? Может он делает небольшой учебный проект или книгу читает, просто заинтересовался темой и решил узнать плюсы, минусы и границы применимости разных вариантов? А таких общих вопросов у нас много, чтобы называть их оффтопиком:  [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427323/198251) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1021/198251) [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460207/198251) [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470453/198251) [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471343/198251).

Comment: @AivanF Давайте без вот этих демагогий, а? Есть установленные на ресурсе нормы, в частности [Stack Overflow на русском > Справка > Как задавать вопросы > Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). И там чётко всё расписано, включая "Обсуждения на любые темы, пересекающиеся с тематикой сайта, приветствуются **в чате**, но не на самом сайте вопросов и ответов." Вот и добро пожаловать. *что человек без опыта ещё скажет?* В данном случае, вероятно "Правила проглядел по диагонали, справку не читал вообще, но мне надо вотпрямщас, так что уж простите и поймите."

Comment: @Akina, на вопрос можно дать объективный ответ, где вы видите проблему? Если ответ тянет не на один том, это не значит, что он не объективный и основан на мнениях.

Comment: @eanmos Просто представьте, что есть дополнительные сведения, которые не указаны. И они такие: имеется свободный доступ к таблицам БД, в принципе не имеется доступа к переменным среды сервера, в т.ч. удалённо (неважно, как именно это сделано, но так есть). И однозначный объективный ответ будет каким? вариант 1... Теперь возьмём другие неуказанные условия: любой имеет свободный доступ к консоли для просмотра переменных среды, в принципе не имеется доступа к таблице пользователей (опять неважно как это сделано). Угу, вариант 2... Вы всё ещё уверены, что "на вопрос можно дать объективный ответ"?

Comment: @Akina, конечно, вы можете рассмотреть один или несколько вариантов в вашем ответе и он будет объективен. Я не говорю о *полноте* ответа, да, для ответа на некоторые вопросы нужно писать целые книги, но неполный ответ -- не значит необъективный. Другими словами, вы немного путаете *полноту* и *объективность*.

Comment: @eanmos Объективный ответ, отвечающий на другой вопрос, не теряет объективности - только толку в нём ноль для вопрошающего. А для того, чтобы дать объективный ответ на именно заданный вопрос, с учётом всех, в т.ч. неназванных, обстоятельств и условий, нужно сначала вытрясти из автора эти обстоятельства и условия. Впрочем, если он впоследствии обнаружит, что из-за излишней лаконичности он ориентировался на ответ объективный, но в его конкретных условиях не очень корректный, а то и вовсе неприменимый - это его проблемы.

Comment: @Akina, толку никогда не будет ноль, т. к. даже если ситуация автора полностью не описывается ответом, он получит новые знания и переймет опыт отвечающего. Более того, при написании ответа нужно ориентироваться не столько на автора вопроса, сколько на всех людей, что прочтут этот вопрос/ответ в дальнейшем.

Comment: @Akina я хотел не чтобы помогли решить конкретный практический вопрос, а хотел узнать более правильную практику решения этой темы. Мне ответили на вопрос и добавили, что безопасности много не бывает, в итоге я понял, как стоит делать, а если кто-то тоже заинтересуется этим вопросом, то может найти на него здесь ответ. Так что ответы вполне были толковыми, я считаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотрим варианты детальнее

### Вариант 1. Хранить одну общую соль для всех паролей пользователей вне БД

```
hash(secret + password)
```

С виду это выглядит безопаснее, ведь если кто-то получит доступ до БД, то соли у него не будет, и наверное восстановить пароли не сможет?..

Но если злоумышленник получит доступ и к БД, и к соли из переменной среды, то для извлечения паролей всё равно надо будет строить радужную таблицу. И если у вас одна соль на всех юзверей, то это гораздо сделать проще. Другая проблема с безопасностью: если злоумышленник (или его соучастник/жертва) имеет доступ к системе как пользователь, то он уже знает 1 пароль и его хэш, возможно сможет менять пароль и смотреть изменения хэша, находить в БД других пользователей с таким же паролем...

Этот вариант похож на принцип [Security through obscurity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (безопасность через неясность/запутывание), а этого принципа советуют избегать и полагаться на более сильные криптографические методы.

### Вариант 2. Хранить свою для каждого пользователя соль в БД с хэшами паролей

```
hash(salt + password)
```

В этом случае, если злоумышленник получит доступ к БД, то вместе с хэшами паролей он получит и соли к ним. Но теперь для извлечения паролей надо будет сгенерировать не одну радужную таблицу на всех, а для каждого пользователя свою! При этом, важно корректно реализовать свою систему работы с юзерами: при смене пароля надо менять и соль, чтобы даже имея старую версию БД, злоумышленник уже не сможет извлечь из этого выгоду.

Этот же способ используется в Django, также его советуют и обосновывают [в аналогичном вопросе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999247/5308802) – советую почитать, там обсуждены разные варианты и их обоснования.

---

Как упомянули в комментариях, вопрос на самом деле спорный и зависит от реализации вашей системы. Если у вас лишь 1 или несколько серверов с полным или слабо защищённым доступом друг до друга, то скорее всего злоумышленник получивший доступ к БД, легко получит доступ и к ОС с переменными окружения, и наоборот, что нивелирует смысл первого варианта. Если же у вас большая и продуманная инфраструктура, доступы к БД и серверам с кодом разграничены, настроены жёсткие группы безопасности, везде используются юзеры с ограничениями и в БД, и в ОС везде, то можно поиметь выгоду с первого способа. Поэтому есть следующий вариант.

### Вариант 3. Смешать оба варианта

Можно совместить лучшее от двух миров, например так:

```
hash(hash(salt + secret) + password)
```

Хотя есть и другие варианты, детали можно найти [всё в том же вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999247/5308802). Но опять же, пользы в этом не сильно больше, чем во втором варианте, особенно если ваша серверная инфраструктура слабо защищена.

Answer (score 3):

Ни то ни другое.

1. Для каждого юзера своя соль - очевидность этого даже не требует доказательств, если будет 1 соль, то под эту соль для всех юзеров генерируется 1 радужная таблица, что существенно облегчает задачу атакующего
2. Соль необходимо хранить отдельно от хэшей. Желательно даже в разных БД, ну или хотя бы в разных таблицах.
3. Поскольку соль по своей природе открыта, то желательно озаботиться перцем ([pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography))), который в отличие от соли надо хранить в секрете: `key = hash(password+pepper+salt)`